# Filter block of text based on a single value in the block of text

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a LDIF file with about 23K of user objects separated by blank lines. Each user object (block of text in the file) has a workforceid value, and I wanted to  remove the user objects (entire block of text) for any user objects which has a workforceid with 5 chars. There are user objects from two different companies and one company has a 5 digit IDs and the others have a 8 digit IDs and I need to conduct data processing on the user objects with 8 digit IDs. Data set example:

```
# zhayangy, Company
dn: cn=zhayangy,o=Company
workforceid: 26000180
street: 699 axian Road
st: Shanghai
preferredname: Zhao, Yangyang
physicaldeliveryofficename: ABC01:
ou: IT Engineering
mail: yangyang.zhao@sample.com
givenname: Yangyang
fullname: Yangyang Zhao
employeetype: Cont
employeestatus: Active
costcenter: ABCD501641
companycategory: abc.com
co: China
city: Shanghai
uid: zhayangy
sn: Zhao
cn: zhayangy
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: ApplicationAttrs
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: Person
objectclass: LoginProperties
objectclass: Top
objectclass: PasswordUser
objectclass: UserAux
objectclass: FolderUser
objectclass: eSystem
objectclass: pwUser
objectclass: AuthAttrs

# mikhaylo, Company
dn: cn=mikhaylo,o=Company
workforceid: 76000838
street: Gradskoe shoe, 11A block 1
preferredname: Mikhaylov, Vladislav
postalcode: 12345
physicaldeliveryofficename: ABW02:
ou: Presales ABCE
mail: vladislav.mikhaylov@sample.com
givenname: Vladislav
fullname: Vladislav Mikhaylov
employeetype: Employee
employeestatus: Active
costcenter: ABCA500189
companycategory: abc.com
co: Russian Federation
city: Moscow
uid: mikhaylo
sn: Mikhaylov
cn: mikhaylo
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: ApplicationAttrs
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: Person
objectclass: LoginProperties
objectclass: Top
objectclass: PasswordUser
objectclass: UserAux
objectclass: FolderUser
objectclass: eSystem
objectclass: pwUser
objectclass: AuthAttrs
```

Using the below command will search return all the records that have workforceid, but I think that is only if the work force ID is the second entry. It would be nice to have a command that finds the workforceid and count the length of the value regardless of where it falls in the object.

Basically I need to some how add the checking for the length such as: if(length($2) == 5 ), but $2 is the second row in the block of text and not the second column in the workforceid row or column. Depeding on how you look at it.

```
awk -v RS='' '/workforceid/ {if ( length($7) == 5 ) print $0}' ORS='\n\n' fullextract.ldif
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please add sample input(say 5-10 lines with made up data), expected output for that sample - this helps in clarity as well as for testing purposes before suggesting solution.. you are also expected to **show** what efforts you've made yourself to solve this.. since you mention blocks are separated by blank lines, I'd suggest you to search for `awk paragraph mode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID you're interested in is $4, not $2 or $7 and all you need is:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' 'length($4) == 8' fullextract.ldif
```

You could've just printed the fields to see that.

If it can be anywhere:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/(^|\n)workforceid: [0-9]{8}(\n|$)/' fullextract.ldif
```

The more robust, general way to approach the problem of data with `tag: value` pairs is to create an array that stores them and then operate on the array, e.g.:

```
awk '
NF {
    rec = rec $0 ORS
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/:.*/,"",tag)
    sub(/[^:]+: /,"",val)
    tag2val[tag] = val
    next
}
{ prt(); rec=""; delete tag2val }
END { prt() }
function prt() {
    if ( length(tag2val["workforceid"]) == 8 ) {
        print rec
    }
}
' file
```

With that it's trivial to add additional test on other fields, only print specific fields, etc. With your particular data you'd have to deal with the "objectclass" fields all having the same tag if you wanted to test or print them individually but that's easily dealt with (e.g. add a counter to uniquely identify each in `val2tag[]` or a separate array just for them, maybe indexed by their values so you can easily use `in` to test for their presence), however you want it handled.

Comment: I updated the sample data to reflect exactly what I have but with masked data values. The ask is to be able to identify a 8 digit workforceID that may exists in any location with in the user obj. For instance the sample objects show the workforceID in the 3rd row, but what if a different object in the file has it in the 5th row?

Comment: OK I added another approach to my answer.

Comment: The robust answer did exactly what I was asking. I have accepted your more robust answer as the solution to my question. The second one liner solution you provided did not pass my testing. In fact it didn't return any objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer here after testing. Please let me know if I am wrong. I'm not confident that it is correct, but I moved the "workforceid" to a different location in the object and it gives me the same count. So I think got it.

```
awk -v RS='' '/workforceid/ {if ( length($7) == 5 ) print $0}' ORS='\n\n' fullextract.ldif
```

Comment: You're wrong. That will not work with the sample input you posted in your question and it's unnecessarily complicated. In your sample and per your description every record contains a workforceid so there's no need to test for it and $7 is the first name of the person identified by preferredname:, Elaine or John. Also there's no reason to make the test on length a separate condition inside the action that's executed when the first condition is true rather than using a compound condition in the first place, and printing $0 is the default action.

Comment: I updated the sample data to reflect exactly what I have but with masked data values. I'm confused on why the data set matters in this case. The ask is to check the workforceID in each user object that is separated by a newline and keep only the blocks of text (entire user objs) that are 8 digits in length. Also, It needs to account for the workforceID attribute & value being in a different row within the object. I.e. currently you see the workforceID being the second attribute in the object, but what happen if a separate obj has the workforceID at the end of the obj.

Comment: My solution did not work as I proposed in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that works. `$7` does not seem to be the work force id. Anyway, here's my solution:

```
awk -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n' '/workforceid: [0-9]{8}/' ldif
```

In other words, if the work force id consists of eight digits, print the record, otherwise don't.

Comment: I updated the sample data to reflect exactly what I have but with masked data values. The ask is to be able to identify a 8 digit workforceID that may exists in any location with in the user obj. For instance the sample objects show the workforceID in the 3rd row, but what if a different object in the file has it in the 5th row?

Comment: Since my solution does not split the record into lines or words, it is unaffected.

Comment: This did not work only if the workforceID is the same spot for all the records. Just like mine, but does not work if you have the workforceID in a different row within the obj.

Comment: It works for me. And in fact, it is virtually the same solution Ed Morton uses.

Comment: as I stated in a comment under his solution, his short solution didn't work either, but his long version did, and so I had to give him the credit as the solution.